# Estimate nominal values of a brushed DC motor

Tags: dc-motor

Is there a good rule of thumb for guessing the nominal values (torque and current) of a brushed DC motor if you know its stall values?

I'm estimating parameters for a small DC motor (~5-10 W). When I look at datasheets for motors of that size, I see continuous values of around 20-30% of the stall values. Is this a good approximation? Or how would you do it? Does this hold true for larger motors as well?

Comment: Check the data sheets for a few larger motors and you will know.

Comment: Ye I guess so. I'm just afraid that motors with datasheets are of higher quality so they might tolerate more than lower quality motors that don't have datasheets.

Comment: But you have data sheets for the smaller ones - you say you read them...

Comment: Yes but that worry holds for small DC motors as well. If I was sure I wouldn't have asked this question in the first place.

Comment: So two things: only buy motors with data sheets, and read the info supplied...

Comment: That would limit my options considerably. Motors with good datasheets are rare and much more expensive.

Comment: So you get what you pay for : buy cheap & get rubbish... your money, your choice.

Comment: dot-dot-dot mike I get your point. But the only motors I've found with continuous values are from maxon motors, they are 60$ a piece at least. I need four of them for a smaller robotics project. I'm not paying ~250 $. Thus, I'm looking for a rule of thumb.

Comment: If you buy motors that are not from reputable suppliers (i.e. suppliers who have not provided data sheets or manufacturer's that have not provided data sheets) you have no guarantee about performance or life expectancy or efficiency or all manner of other things that you should pay money for. How much do you value your time - how many hours messing around with inadequate motors might you spend until you realize they may not be suitable? How about going for stepper motors as an alternative?

Comment: 20-30% of stall values is a not unreasonable place to start, though of course 10% is safer. What are your failure modes? Is this a 'look Ma' project, where failure only costs you a little time rebuilding something, or is it going to seriously impact your reputation or somebody's life? It may make sense to simply build it and see how long it works for. That's easier than testing motors in artificial conditions, and trying to relate those to service conditions. I've found I always learn something from just building something, so I always allow for a quick and dirty first cut on every project.

Comment: @Andyaka and Neil_Uk, exactly the kind of advice I was looking for, thanks. This is definitely a "look Ma" project. And I'm a beginner so I think buying a few motors to experiment with is a good idea anyway.